# Avoid displaying out of stock products in upsell section

Tags: attributes, filter, up-sells

Under Configuration -> Inventory -> Display Out of Stock Products I have set it to Yes because out of stock products are accessible by Search Engines though I don't want the out of stock products to show up in Upsell section. Is there any way to achieve this by applying filters? Below is the entire code of my upsell.phtml.

```
<?php if (count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>

    <div class="collateral-box up-sell">

        <div class="head"><h4><?php echo $this->__('You may also be interested in the following product(s):') ?></h4></div>

        <table cellspacing="0" class="generic-product-grid catalog-listing" id="upsell-product-table">

            <?php // $this->setColumnCount(4); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>

            <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>

            <?php for ($_i = 0; $_i < $this->getRowCount(); $_i++): ?>

                <tr>

                    <?php for ($_j = 0; $_j < $this->getColumnCount(); $_j++): ?>

                        <?php if ($_link = $this->getIterableItem()): ?>

                            <?php $_link = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId()); ?>

                            <td> 

                                <p class="product-image"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(125) ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a></p>

                                <h5><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($_link->getUrlPath()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?></a></h5>

                                <?php //echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true) ?>

                                <?php //echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link) ?>

                            </td>

                        <?php else: ?>

                            <td class="empty-product">&nbsp;</td>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endfor; ?>

                </tr>

            <?php endfor; ?>

        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('upsell-product-table')</script>

    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe this event `catalog_product_upsell`.
It receives as a parameter the list of upsell products. You can check if they are out of stock and remove them from the collection.

```
public function filterUpsells($observer) {
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if (!$item->getIsSalable()) {
            $collection->removeItemByKey($item->getId())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific as I am very new to Magento and php?

Comment: @KevinS. This could help a lot: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: I did visited the link and it says **You’ve followed a link to a topic that doesn’t exist yet. If permissions allow, you may create it by using the “Create this page” button.**

Comment: @KevinS. Don't click it. Copy/paste it in your browser. For some reason the SO wiki parser is cutting the link. The link ends with 'method'. Just copy it all "www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method"

Comment: @KevinS Damn it...I can't seam to post the link properly. Just google "magento event observer" and click on the first link.

Comment: I did tried to follow the instruction but it is out of my head.

Comment: What should be the `<method></method>` in config.xml?

Comment: @KevinS. If you use my example it should be `filterUpsells`. As the name of the method you call.

Comment: Thanks.. i possible can you review my codes and file location that I have posted at the following locations? 1. `config.xml : http://pastebin.com/MjxpcdRp` 2. `Observer.php : http://pastebin.com/37xWEpeQ` 3. `kevz_upsellobserver.xml : http://pastebin.com/NeSqz8Aa`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13412/discussion-between-marius-and-kevin-s)

Comment: without this event, Can I get upsell prduct collection (Only in stock products)